# Can I Copy/Paste Keyframes from one Mask Effect into Another in Premiere Pro 2023?

Tags: keyframes, mask, premiere-pro

I have two effects on a clip where I have to apply motion tracking to their respective masks. Gaussian Blur and Lumetri Color, respectively.

[image]

But I have a large number of clips I have to apply these to, and I would like to know if there's a way to copy the keyframes from one mask, to the other within the same clip. They are both tracking the same object. So it would cut my time almost in half if I could just run the motion tracker in one effect mask, and then just use those keyframes for the other.

So far, I haven't been able to find a way to do this. Standard Copy and Paste just lets me move the keyframes around the same timeline of the effect mask it originated from.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in Premiere. It sounds like a job for After Effects.